# Finding the UMVUE of $e^{3\lambda}$ in Poi($\lambda$)

Tags: self-study, inference, poisson-distribution, moment-generating-function, umvue

> Let $ X = (X_1, ... , X_n)$ iid variables coming from Poisson
> distribution with mean $\lambda$.
> Find the UMVUE of $e^{3\lambda}$.

I tried understanding the solution below (in the possible duplicate link) but couldn't come up with appropriate weights.
So I thought of using the moment-generating function and Lehman-Scheffe Theorem.

For starters, we know $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i$ is a complete and sufficient statistic (C.S.S) and has Poi(n$\lambda$) distribution.

Then the moment-generating function of $M_{S_n}(t) = e^{n\lambda(e^t-1)} = E(e^{S_n t})$.

So if we let $n\lambda(e^t-1) = 3\lambda \iff t = \ln(3/n + 1)$, we have $E(e^{S_n(\ln(3/n+1)}) = e^{3\lambda}$. Since it is a function of the C.S.S, we can say  $e^{S_n(\ln(3/n+1)}$ is the UMVUE.

Am I missing or overlooking anything here? Would appreciate some advice or insights.

[Possible duplicate](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/403516)

Comment: You can't have $E[e^{S_n\log(3/n+1)}]$ as the UMVUE because it's not an estimator; it's an expectation using the unknown $\lambda$. If you drop the expectation then it's an estimator and seems to be unbiased

Comment: edited thank you!